# Capture group subtraction/negation

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I can't seem to substract or negatiate captured group.
Given those string examples:

- "aa"
- "ab"

And Regex: `@"([a-z])[^\1]"` or `@"([a-z])[\w-[\1]]"`
I would expect for the first one to fail matching and for the second one to succeed, but it succeeds in both cases. I am facing a bit more complicated regex, but I simplified it to this level. Is syntax different for referencing captured group in square bracets?

EDIT: Unfortunately I was wrong thinking this simplified version will be good for the real one. Here it is.

Suppose strings:

1. "abcdf"
2. "aabb"
3. "aacbb"
4. "aacaa"

And Regex: `@"([a-z])\1.*?(?!(\1))\2"`

I would expect 2. and 3. to be true. 4 should be false, because "aa" == "aa"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside character class `[]` the regex interpreter follows different rules. Think to the special treatment reserved to dash char `-` used to make ranges of chars (ie. `[a-z]`).

So the `\1` inside is treated as the ASCII code `1` and `[^\1]` means: every char that is not the ascii control char `1` (*start of heading*).

**UPDATE**

For your edit your are close, try this regex (i don't think you need the lazy modifier in the dot section `.*?`):

```
@"^([a-z])\1.*((?!\1)[a-z])\2$"
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF1xR0/3)

**Legenda**

```
^              # match start of the string
 ([a-z])       # Capturing Group 1 (\1): a single lowercase letter
 \1            # the same char of \1 again
 .*            # any char zero or more times
 ((?!\1)[a-z]) # Capturing Group 2 (\2): a lowercase letter that is not equal to \1
 \2            # the same char of \2 again
$
```

Comment: Thank you! Also didn't know about that useful website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
@"([a-z])(?!\1)."
```

And anchors if necessary.

```
@"^([a-z])(?!\1).$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yE8jS1/2)

Comment: See my edit please. I am reading about lookaround, but it doesn't come so easy for me. Could you provide solution to my 2nd example?

Answer (score 1):

In your example

```
([a-z])\1.*?(?!(\1))\2
```

The expression `([a-z])` will capture one character. the proceeding `\1` will match the same character again. So thus far we are requiring that we have two of the same characters in a row.

`.*?` will then match anything, until terminated by a a character that is not `\1`.

The final `\2` does not exist, so it will always fail the regex. The second grouping parenthesis are in the lookaround, and lookarounds do not capture.

If the final `\2` was not there, then the match would start over again.

So if you remove the final  `\2` you will have matches for 2,3 and 4 that always capture `aa` and `bb` since the regex will start again. You can add a terminating character to prevent this, but then we need to know the format of the data. For example, are you matching a single or multiple lines?